# geom_histogram missing data from plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I have data:

```
> dat
 slopes     sig
1  -1.24285       insignificant
2   0.01733       insignificant
3  -0.00050       insignificant
4  -0.06455       insignificant
5   0.00608       insignificant
6   0.01669       insignificant
7  -0.00751       insignificant
8  -0.00987 p <0.05
9  -0.00069       insignificant
10  0.00482       insignificant
11 -0.00446       insignificant
12 -0.00035       insignificant
13 -0.00205       insignificant
14  0.00585       insignificant
15  0.00507       insignificant
16  0.00002       insignificant
17 -0.00279       insignificant
18 -0.00580 p <0.05
19  0.00399       insignificant
20 -0.00647 p <0.05
21 -0.00268       insignificant
22 -0.00696       insignificant
23 -0.00678       insignificant
24  0.00034       insignificant
25 -0.00208       insignificant
26 -0.00012       insignificant
27 -0.00027       insignificant
28  0.00082       insignificant
29  0.01113       insignificant
30 -0.00171       insignificant
31  0.00134       insignificant
32 -0.14532       insignificant
33 -0.00433       insignificant
34  0.00440       insignificant
35  0.00369       insignificant
36 -0.00063       insignificant
37  0.01138       insignificant
38  0.00323       insignificant
39 -0.03902 p <0.05
```

Which I am trying to plot as a stacked histogram in ggplot2 using the following code:

```
 ggplot(dat,aes(x=slopes,fill=sig))+
  labs(title='Log(Biomass+1)') +

  geom_histogram(data=dat,position='stack',aes(x=slopes),color='black',binwidth=diff(range(dat$slopes))/20)+   # without change.
      scale_fill_manual(values=c('darkgray','pink'),name='Significance') +
      labs(x='Slope', y='Frequency', size=20) +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)),
            axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.25)),
            plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,10))+
      theme_bw()
```

But not all of the data is being plotted.  In fact, my resulting figure is:

[image]

How do I get the histogram to show all of the data?

Comment: You've truncated the graph by setting the limits of the y axis no higher than 10, which chops off a fair bit of data.

Comment: wow..thanks!  my followup question is then, how do I only set a lower limit for y axis, not the upper limit?

Comment: Maybe `limits = c(0,NA)`, but be aware than any limit setting in a `scale_*` function will discard data _first_ and then plot. `coord_cartesian` will "zoom" in on a specific region. For instance, note what happens when you do `limits = c(5,NA)`.